# How to remove a line from an .ini file with VBS script

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, hta

I am trying to write a VBS Script to remove a line from an .ini file.
However, when I run it, the new file (as well as the backup) is created and renamed , but the line I want removed is still there?
How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const OpenAsASCII = 0
Const CreateIfNotExist = True

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const OverwriteExisting = True

'Making a backup of the file
objFSO.CopyFile "C:\notes.ini" , "C:\notesBACKUP.ini"

'Setting input of file
strInput = "C:\notes.ini"
Set objInput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInput, ForReading)

'Setting temp output for new file with omitted line
strOutput = "C:\notes2.ini"

Set objOutput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strOutput, _
ForWriting, CreateIfNotExist, OpenAsASCII)


Do Until objInput.AtEndOfStream

strLine = objInput.ReadLine

'Line with EXTMGR to be replaced when copying to new file
If (InStr(LCase(strLine), "EXTMGR") > 0) Then

'New line replacing old one
strLine = "#Deleted"
End If

objOutput.WriteLine strLine
Loop


objInput.Close
objOutput.Close


'Deleting the original file
objFSO.DeleteFile(strInput)

'Renaming the new file (with line removed) to the original filename
objFSO.MoveFile "C:\notes2.ini" , "C:\notes.ini"
```

Comment: You are doing an LCASE conversion of a string and then looking for a string in ALL CAPS - seems odd.  What is the line in the INI file you're looking to replace? Can you share that?

Comment: true - did not notice that, was using parts from an old script I had - 
here is the line I need commented out (or deleted):
EXTMGR_ADDINS=NCExtMgr

Comment: If (InStr(strLine, "EXTMGR_ADDINS") > 0)  does that not work?

Comment: Yup, just went back and tried that, works perfect. Thanks, didn't even notice that from before, doh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing an `LCASE` conversion of a string and then looking for a string in ALL CAPS.

Change code to:
`If (InStr(strLine, "EXTMGR_ADDINS") > 0)`